# How to reconstruct MMW image using electrical field in each direction at Reciever points

Tags: python, matlab, signal-processing, imaging, back-projection

I have used a structure including 109 Receivers and 4 transmitters in order to do MMW imaging(multistatic imaging). Imaging was done in 3 different frequencies. So, now I have electrical field in each direction at each receiver point resulted from each transmitter at those frequencies. I just want to know how can I implement it in matlab or python.
Can you give me a step-by-step guideline, sample code or document for implementation?
Actually, this is the best article I found in this subject, But i can not understand its implementation perfectly:

"Walk-through millimeter wave imaging testbed
based on double multistatic cross arrays"

**UPDATE**

Here is the link to the available data:

[nearfield data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1pyp4LvzBPAo5wf6O2omFKrfwU8FxK0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and fix the hyperlink?

Comment: perhaps better asked on the SEs for electrical engineering or physics or DSP.

Comment: @foxpal hello, thank you for your suggestion. I have placed nearfield data.

Comment: I believe this needs a dedicated piece of software, which I think would be very difficult to implement from scratch. I'd ask someone who is already familiar with this kind of work, like a supervisor or a coworker.